# How to change the scroll physics using CarouselSlider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, carousel

For example, if someone swiped the carousel once quickly, it would spin from 1 to 100 (currently its quite stiff and moves about 2 places).

I have tried to achieve this by creating a CustomScrollPhysics class that extends ScrollPhysics, and overriding the SpringDescription but this doesn't seem to work and not really sure if this is the right way to go about this?

```
class CarouselSpring extends StatefulWidget {
  const CarouselSpring({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CarouselSpring> createState() => _CarouselSpringState();
}

class _CarouselSpringState extends State<CarouselSpring> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final List<int> items = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      items.add(i);
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: size.height * 0.50,
          width: size.width * 0.50,
          child: CarouselSlider(
            items:
                items.map((e) => Center(child: Text(e.toString()))).toList(),
            options: CarouselOptions(
              scrollPhysics: CustomScrollPhysics(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  static final SpringDescription customSpring =
      SpringDescription.withDampingRatio(mass: 1, stiffness:99);

  @override
  SpringDescription get spring => customSpring;
}
```

Comment: read https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics/applyTo.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the link provided by @pskink, I just needed to override the **applyTo** method in the CustomScrollPhysics class which extends ScrollPhysics.

Now I can adjust the scroll physics (e.g. here can spin through really fast on one flick).

[image]

```
class CustomScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  static final SpringDescription customSpring =
      SpringDescription.withDampingRatio(mass: 200, stiffness:1);

  @override
  CustomScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics? ancestor){
    return CustomScrollPhysics();
  }

  @override
  SpringDescription get spring => customSpring;
}
```